# Centrado absoluto en android

Tags: android, diseño, views

Tengo problemas a la hora de centrar 2 elementos en mi interface android, el primero es un imagenview, intente cambiar el tamaño de la imagen pensando que era por su tamaño pero no pasa nada, se ve de esta forma:

[image: imagen inicial]

Cuando lo que busco es algo de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es este:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Como se puede ver usen la propiedad:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

En el imagenview pero no ajusta el tamaño.

Lo mismo pasa con los textview ¿No tienes una cuenta? mi codigo es:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_horizontal_login"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextWhite"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_username"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextWhite">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:text="@string/btn_login"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:theme="@style/RaisedButtonDark"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/dontHaveAccount"
                    android:text="@string/dont_have_account"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_donthaveaccount"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/createHere"
                    android:text="@string/create_here"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_donthaveaccount"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dontHaveAccount"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Como se puede ver en el RelativeLayout use:

```
android:gravity="center
```

Pero tampoco centro el contenido.

Comment: pones android:layout_width="wrap_content", por eso se ve asi... tu imagen es más grande que la pantalla, prueba poniendo un tamaño fijo android:layout_width="200dp"

Comment: Tienes razón, probé cambiándole el tamaño y si funciono, pero no tendría problemas con las demás resoluciones de pantalla? hay alguna forma de hacer esto dinamicamente?

Answer (score 0):

En este caso estas usando un [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html), si deseas centrar tus elementos, tienes la ventaja de realizarlo mediante la vista de diseño, selecciona tu elemento y en al visualizar los circulos, arrastralos a los 4 extremos, con esto al ejecutar tu aplicación el elemp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alguna sugerencia respecto al texto de la parte inferior?